# What is the purpose of these two kdb functions?

Tags: database, kdb

I have not used kdb for a while. I am trying to understand these two functions:

```
trade:([]sym:n?`sym;time:10:30:00.0+til
n;price:n?3.3e;size:n?9;ex:n?ex);
quote:([]sym:n?`sym;time:10:30:00.0+til
n;bid:n?3.3e;ask:n?3.3e;bsize:n?9;asize:n?9;ex:n?ex);
{@[;`sym;`p#]`sym xasc x}each`trade`quote;
d:2014.08.07 2014.08.08 2014.08.09 2014.08.10 2014.08.11; /Date vector can also be changed by the user
dt:{[d;t].[dst;(`$string d;t;`);:;value t]};
```

I am trying to understand this one
`` @[;`sym;`p#]`sym xasc x}each`trade`quote; ``

what's `p# here?  so from trade table and quote tables, they pass sym to the function? And this function is just order sym? What does everything do here?

Also this one `` dt:{[d;t].[dst;(`$string d;t;`);:;value t]}; ``, is this a saving function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`` `p# `` is the parted attribute which is applied to lists where all the distinct values are adjacent and creates a mapping of all the distinct values in the list to the first index of where they appear. This allows for faster look ups and queries. The parted attribute is typically used on tables stored on disk, whereas the grouped attribute (`` `g# ``) is used for tables in memory.

The function `` @[`trade;`sym;`p#] `` applies the parted attribute to the sym column of the trade table but can only be applied if the distinct values are adjacent. `` `sym xasc `trade `` sorts the trade table in ascending order by the sym column. For trade and quote data, normally time would be sorted within sym before applying the parted attribute.

Putting these two expressions together
we get `` @[;sym`p#] `sym xasc `trade ``, which is the same as
`` @[`sym xasc `trade;sym;`p#] ``. This applies the parted attribute to the sym column on the trade table, which has been sorted by sym.

If `dst` is the path to a directory then `` dt:{[d;t].[dst;(`$string d;t;`);:;value t]} `` for each date in a list of dates `d`, and for a table `t`, it is saving down the table. `` dt[d;`quote] `` would save the quote table in the following way

```
dst
├── 2014.08.07
│   ├── quote
│   │   ├── asize
│   │   ├── ask
│   │   ├── bid
│   │   ├── bsize
│   │   ├── ex
│   │   ├── sym
│   │   └── time
├── 2014.08.07
│   ├── quote
│   │   ├── asize
.
.
.
```

Comment: thanks! just one question. how come it doesnt use x ? like this {@[x;`sym;`p#]`sym xasc x}each`trade`quote; why does it just leave blank for the table parameter?

Comment: x is unsorted, so trying to apply the parted attribute directly to it is not guaranteed to succeed. ```@[;`sym;`p#]``` is a projection and the sorted table is the first argument. You can read more on projections here: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/application/#projection